# Get() call not returning a value from unit testing but API call does in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

Using Test>Debug>All Tests I can see that the value 749 is being passed as the id from my TestMethod to the Controller but the record.count is identifying that no matches are found. When the testing is loaded the db(dbcontext) appears to have no information within it, whereas when it's built and ran normally it's all there.

I'm currently using Entity Framework and Webapi to add some context.

Using Postman I pass http://localhost:54047/api/Records/GetParticipant/749 and it returns the record matching 749 and I can also see the value in the database, how can this occur?

**Test Method**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Get_ShouldReturnCorrectParticipant()
{
    var testParticipants = GetTestParticipants(); //Returns List
    RecordsController controller = new RecordsController();
    var result = controller.GetParticipant(749);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

**RecordController.cs**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<ParticipantDTO>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetParticipant(int id)
{
    var records = from n in db.Records
            join u in db.Users on n.WhoAssignedPlanning.Id equals u.Id into usergp
            from u in usergp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where n.ID == id
            select new ParticipantDTO()
            {
                ID = n.ID,
                BobId = n.BobId,
                Name = n.Firstname + " " + n.Lastname,
                Notes = n.Notes,
                Firstname = n.Firstname,
                Lastname = n.Lastname,
                Region = n.Region,
                Suburb = n.Suburb,
                Address = n.Address,
                DOB = n.DOB,
                WhoAssignedPlanning = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
            };
    if (records.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(records);
}
```

Comment: you can right click at the test method and then debug

Comment: you are doing it wrong you have to mock the `dbcontext` try taking a look at https://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/writing-unit-tests-for-asp-net-web-api-controller